# Does a target get a Dodge check, for effects they cannot see?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

An Area effect allows a dodge check, typically, unless it is also Perception-based. However, what if a target cannot see it--such as an effect with Subtle, that they cannot detect? Do they still get a chance to dodge?

The power in question is a sort of "aura" that exudes from the PC, meant to automatically effect everyone in an area, in their mind. An invisible "field" of affliction.

In short: Does a person get to dodge an effect they cannot see? And is there any penalty for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut impulse is that they still get the Dodge save. In 2E, this was a FAQ question answered by the developer, Steve Kenson ([relevant ORQ](http://www.atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?t=15143)):

> **What happens to your Reflex saving throws when you are flat-footed or stunned?**
>
> Nothing. Being flat-footed or stunned has no effect on Reflex saves. A helpless character, however, is unable to make Reflex saving throws and automatically fails them. This includes other conditions that cause a character to become helpless, such as being paralyzed or unconscious.

Since the effect of something like Subtle is indicated that it "may be used to catch a target unaware and may in some cases qualify for a surprise attack", I'd say it falls under the same category.

But since there is no official answer, it's up to the GM. If you want to justify it, Steve Kenson indicated that reflexive dodging (however it works for something like a Subtle Affliction... maybe not inhaling when the gas is at its thickest, or rapidly blinking one's mind's eye) is just that, reflexive, so it works just as well when caught by surprise.